# Kivy - python - multiple widgets in recycleview row

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to make a recycleview that has multiple labels in each recycleview row. In my specfic example I would like to have 3 labels in each row: 1 label containing the item index, one label containing an item from one dataset, and another label from another dataset

In this example (taken from the kivy examples) we have a recycleview where each row in the recycleview contains a single label:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior

Builder.load_string('''
<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True
''')


items_1= {'apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'pineapple'}
items_2= {'dog', 'cat', 'rat', 'bat'}

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in items_1]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I would like each recycleview row to have 3 labels: first label is the index, second label is items_1 and third label is items_2. Like this:

0 apple dog

1 banana cat

2 pear rat

3 pineapple bat

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a similar solution and could not find it. I do not think PalimPalim has really answered the question since I think the Ben t was looking for multiple label widgets treated as a single line.

In this case you use a custom widget for GridLayout and specify it's structure.

```
<SelectableLabel>:
# Draw a background to indicate selection
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
label1_text: 'label 1 text'
label2_text: 'label 2 text'
label3_text: 'label 3 text'
pos: self.pos
size: self.size
Label:
    id: id_label1
    text: root.label1_text
Label:
    id: id_label2
    text: root.label2_text
Label:
    id: id_label3
    text: root.label3_text
```

In applying your data into the RV, you will need to restructure the dictionary to reflect the label layout

```
class RV(RecycleView):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    paired_iter = zip(items_1, items_2)
    self.data = []
    for i1, i2 in paired_iter:
        d = {'label2': {'text': i1}, 'label3': {'text': i2}}
        self.data.append(d)
```

Finally in the refresh_view_attrs, you will specify .label_text which is bound to each label, or you can use label id's.

```
def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
    ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
    self.index = index
    self.label1_text = str(index)
    self.label2_text = data['label2']['text']
    self.ids['id_label3'].text = data['label3']['text']  # As an alternate method of assignment
    return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
        rv, index, data)
```

The entire code is below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior

Builder.load_string('''
<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    label1_text: 'label 1 text'
    label2_text: 'label 2 text'
    label3_text: 'label 3 text'
    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
    Label:
        id: id_label1
        text: root.label1_text
    Label:
        id: id_label2
        text: root.label2_text
    Label:
        id: id_label3
        text: root.label3_text

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True
''')


items_1 = {'apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'pineapple'}
items_2 = {'dog', 'cat', 'rat', 'bat'}


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, GridLayout):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    cols = 3

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        self.label1_text = str(index)
        self.label2_text = data['label2']['text']
        self.ids['id_label3'].text = data['label3']['text']  # As an alternate method of assignment
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        paired_iter = zip(items_1, items_2)
        self.data = []
        for i1, i2 in paired_iter:
            d = {'label2': {'text': i1}, 'label3': {'text': i2}}
            self.data.append(d)
        # can also be performed in a complicated one liner for those who like it tricky
        # self.data = [{'label2': {'text': i1}, 'label3': {'text': i2}} for i1, i2 in zip(items_1, items_2)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

the easiest way is to change from a `RecycleBoxLayout` to `RecycleGridLayout` with
3 columns and using the following list `items = [0, "apple", "dog", 1, "banana", "cat", 2, "pear", "rat", 3,  "pineapple", "bat"]` Obviously, you could stick to you original list data structure and merge them together to form the list above, but I will leave that for you ;).

Another option which should be possible is to add to the `RecycleBoxLayout` a `RecycleBoxLayout` with an `horizontal` orientation per row.

---

This is all the python code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior

Builder.load_string('''
<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True
        cols: 3
''')


items = [0, "apple", "dog", 1, "banana", "cat", 2, "pear", "rat", 3,  "pineapple", "bat"]

class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in items]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so consider accepting or if it just helped you, you may consider upvoting it.

Comment: Just a minor correction... While using RecycleGridLayout, in <RV> inside Builder, orientation cannot be 'vertical'. I changed it to << orientation: 'lr-tb' >> and now it works as desired,